# Dependency mismatch with Jquery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am pretty new to Jquery, I am using validation rule against my textbox. The problem is when i mark textbox is mandatory n user doesn't input any value then it doesn't show any validation message. I have associated another validation message for textbox tht the value shu be in range and which works when user provides any input.

```
$.validator.addMethod("requiredRangeFunction", function(value, element) {debugger
            $.validator.messages["requiredRangeFunction"] = 
    jQuery.format(
      $(element).attr('ErrorMessage') ? $(element).attr('ErrorMessage') : "Please enter the value between {0} and {1}",
      $(element).attr('MinValue'), 
      $(element).attr('MaxValue')
     );

    return  this.optional(element) || ((value > Number($(element).attr('MinValue')) && (value < Number($(element).attr('MaxValue')))));
}, "Please enter valid value.");
```

issue is with this.optional(element) which returns dependency mismatch when user doesnt provide any input.

my textbox can be optional too so i require to call this.optional(element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing for (this.optional(element) == true) worked for me.

So in your case it would be:

```
return  (this.optional(element) == true) || ((value > Number($(element).attr('MinValue')) && (value < Number($(element).attr('MaxValue')))));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, this.optional(element) returns "dependency-mismatch", does anyone have a solution for this?!

Answer (score 1):

(Opposite from Nav's solution)

```
return (this.optional(element) != false) || test;
```

this works for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the

```
return this.optional(element) || <test condition>
```

by

```
var r = $(element).rules();
var req=(this.objectLength(r))?r.required:false;
return !req || <test condition>;
```

May be it will be enouth:

```
var req=r.required; // true, false or undefined.
```

Assume that undefined is the same as false for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

Optional means the user doesn't have to provide any input.  If there is no input, it doesn't need to be validated.

Comment: yeah i know that optional means user doesn't need to prvoide any input but i want to validate when user doesn't provide any input and control is marked mandatory